# How do I make this plugin translation-ready?

Tags: localization

I am in need of help with making a plugin translation ready. I do not have any experience in doing this what so ever, nor in php... If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

This is the code that I have:

```
    // adauga meniu in bara
add_action('admin_menu', 'googleharti_add_to_sidebar');
function wporg_shortcodes_init() {
    function wporg_shortcode($atts = [], $content = null) {
        // do something to $content
        $content = '<div id="continut_shortcode" class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-4">'
                    . '<div class="row">' 
                    .   '<div class="row margin-bottom">'
                    .       '<div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" id="addressInput" placeholder="City..." /></div>'
                    .   '</div>'
                    .   '<div class="row row-eq-height margin-bottom">'
                    .       '<div class="col-md-6">Distance'
                    .           '<select id="radiusSelect" label="Radius">'
                    .               '<option value="10">10 km</option>'
                    .               '<option value="20">20 km</option>'
                    .               '<option value"30" selected>30 km</option>'
                    .               '<option value="40">40 km</option>'
                    .               '<option value="50">50 km</option>'
                    .           '</select>'
                    .       '</div>' 
                    .       '<div class="col-md-6">&nbsp;'
                    .           '<input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search" onclick="searchNearCity();" class="button"/>'
                    .       '</div>'
                    .   '</div>'
                    .   '<div class="row vertical-center">'
                    .       '<div class="col-xs-5"><hr></div>'
                    .       '<div class="col-xs-1">or</div>'
                    .       '<div class="col-xs-6"><hr></div>'
                    .   '</div>'
                    .   '<div class="row margin-bottom-x4">'
                    .       '<div class="col-md-12">'
                    .            '<button type="submit" id="useMyLocation" onclick="trackMe(true, true);" class="button"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Use my current location</button>'
                    .       '</div>'
                    .   '</div>'
                    . '</div>' 
                    . '<div class="row">'
                    .   '<div id="rezultate" style="overflow-y: scroll; height:265px; border-radius: 5px;">'  
                    .       '<p id="text_header">HERE ARE YOUR CLOSEST GARDEN CENTERS</p>'
                    .       '<ol id="gmap_results"></ol>' 
                    .   '</div>'
                    . '</div>'
                . '</div>'
                . '<div class="col-md-8">'
                .   '<div id="map"></div>'
                . '</div></div></div>';
```

(I guess it is obvious for you, but) What I need to make translatable are this texts:
1. City...
2. Distance
3. Search
4. or
5. Use my current location
6. HERE ARE YOUR CLOSEST GARDEN CENTERS

Comment: Can you explain further what you mean by translation ready? I see you've tagged this qtranslate, have you contacted qtranslate support? 3rd party plugin support is offtopic here. Or are you talking about the built in i11n system in WP for static strings? Please clarify, and please understand that any answer will involve an understanding of basic PHP, you won't get copypasta, and if you did, you'd still need an understanding to be able to use it for more than 1 language

Comment: that is some seriously impressive commitment to concatenation! For translate-ready coding practices for Wordpress plugins, take a read of: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/how-to-internationalize-your-plugin/

Comment: What I understand of being translation-ready, is to appear in WPML when I scan the plugin and to be able to translate it :)

For some reason when I tagged it, I got this suggestion (qtranslate) by default, but now that you mentioned it I guess it is not the right tag... I needed some points of some sort to chose other tags...

 I tried by imitating the examples in your link but it was a trial and error method for me, with no result. Something like this:                         
'<p id="text_header"> __( 'HERE ARE YOUR CLOSEST GARDEN CENTERS', 'googleharti') </p>'

Comment: that is pretty much it, just remember the function calls must be "outside" the single quotes, ie.  `'<p id="text_header">' . __( 'HERE ARE YOUR CLOSEST GARDEN CENTERS', 'googleharti') .'</p>'`

Comment: @majick that is great, thank you. I managed to translate 4 out of 6 strings based on your advice. The other 2 are somehow different, like this: `'<input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search" onclick="searchNearCity();" class="button"/>'` so it doesn't work this way `'<input type="button" id="searchButton" value=" __( 'Search', 'googleharti')" onclick="searchNearCity();" class="button"/>'` Do you know the correct code? Alex

Comment: So I resolved the one with "Search". I changed this `'<input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Search" onclick="searchNearCity();" class="button"/>'` to this `'<button type="button" id="searchButton" onclick="searchNearCity();" class="button">' . __('Search', 'googleharti') .'</button>'`. I am left with this one that I still do not know how to translate `'<div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" id="addressInput" placeholder="City..." /></div>'` Any ideas would be great!

Comment: again you just need to close out the single quotes, concatenate with a `.` and reopen them: `'<div class="col-md-12"><input type="text" id="addressInput" placeholder="' . __('City...','googleharti') . '" /></div>'`

Comment: @majick those nasty quotes... :D I've spent at least 10 hours trying to figure this translation thing out, but google wasn't my friend. Thank you so much, I am really grateful and wouldn't have done it if it wasn't for your help. I feel awful for doing this, but I have found 2 other strings from the same plugin (but different file) that I do not know how to resolve. I respect your time and effort, and if you still have the patience to help me with this ones I would be forever grateful, if not, I will understand completely. In any case, I will write them in the following comment.

Comment: First one is (view on map): `}   jQuery("<li><strong>" + name + "</strong><br/><small>" + address + telephone + "</small><br/><a href=\"#\" onclick=\"moveToMarker(" + markerPos + "); return false;\"><small>View on map</small></a></li><hr/>").appendTo("#gmap_results");
  }` . The second one is (you are here): `infoWindow.setPosition(temp);
        infoWindow.setContent("You are here!");
        infoWindow.open(map);
        map.setCenter(temp);
  
        if (searchAfterwards == true) {
          searchLocationsNear(pos, leaveWindowOpen);
        }
      }, function() {`

Comment: javascript is different, since you can't "do" PHP in javascript, see the example for `wp_localize_script` for how to do this: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script